# Lync 2010 UMCA 3.0 schedule conference join users automatically

Tags: c#, .net, lync-2010, ucma

I have implemented a service, that is capable of scheduling conference meetings in Lync 2010, that can be used for external users using the WEB client.

But there is one problem still. I want to be able to schedule meetings far into the future, and when a user loggs in via the WEB client, all the invited users should automatically be added to the conference. Is this possible? And do I have to configure this on the Lync server, or can this be achieved when I schedule the meeting (in my C# code).

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the meeting URI for your scheduled conference with the invitee.  You can get the meeting URI when you schedule the conference in your C# code. You can use the conference property options to control whether the user waits in a lobby or is directly admitted into conference.